# Как отловить ответ на нужный опрос в aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Помогите понять, почему такой хэндлер не отрабатывает?

```
from aiogram import Router, F


@router.poll_answer(F.poll_id == POLL_ID)
async def make_someting(poll_answer: types.PollAnswer):
    #some code
```

До этого я создаю опрос, сохраняю его id в переменую POLL_ID и отправляю его пользователю. Ответ на опрос проскакивает мимо хэндлера, который я написал выше.
POLL_ID записывается корректно, вероятно вопрос именно в условии внутри декоратора.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71652136/poll-in-python-aiogram

Comment: Как в целом принять ответ на опрос я понимаю, вопрос скорее про то, как фильтровать ответы на опрос с нужным poll_id.

Comment: делаешь все что там, и потом в самом хендлере проверку if poll_answer.option_ids == [номер ответа, 
начиная с 0]: